# Customise the Json in Android Java

Tags: java, android, json

I have `Json` like this..

I used Gson

```
[
  {
    "quantity": 12.0,
    "product_gid": 15
  },
  {
    "quantity": 6.0,
    "product_gid": 18
  }
]
```

I used Json.put

```
{
  "ACTION": "Insert",
  "soheader_gid": 0,
  "emp_gid": 59,
  "custid": 120
}
```

Now I need to customize the data as

```
{
  "parms": {
    "emp_gid": 59,
    "soheader_gid": 0,
    "custid": "120",
    "ACTION": "Insert",
    "data": {
      "sodetails": [
        {
          "quantity": 12.0,
          "product_gid": 15
        },
        {
          "quantity": 6.0,
          "product_gid": 18
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Even this is simple in `Python` or `.net`, I am confused how to do in Java Android.

Comment: do you want to create the last json ?

Comment: Yes. I need last Json

Comment: ok wait let me help you out..

Comment: Can you elaborate your question. What exactly you wanted to do?

Comment: I need to Combine Two or More JSon Object. It contains List. for EG : {"params:"A":1,"B":2,"DATA":{"Z":[{"X":1},{"X":2}]}}

Answer (score 1):

Hi you can try below code to construct your json,

```
   String message;
    JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
    JSONObject json1 = new JSONObject();
    JSONObject json2 = new JSONObject();
    JSONObject json3 = new JSONObject();
    JSONObject json4 = new JSONObject();
    JSONArray jsonArray=new JSONArray();
    json1.put("emp_gid", 59);
    json1.put("soheader_gid", 0);
    json1.put("custid", 120);
    json1.put("ACTION", "Insert");
    json1.put("data", json2);
    json.put("parms", json1);
    json3.put("quantity", 12.0);
    json3.put("product_gid", 15);
    json4.put("quantity", 6.0);
    json4.put("product_gid", 18);
    jsonArray.put(json3);
    jsonArray.put(json4);
    json2.put("sodetails", jsonArray);
    message = json.toString();
```

@NOTE:  above code is just a process to convert your two json in single one.

Comment: The quantity comes in a N number of Times. So i need to added it dynamically.

Comment: I worked out and find. But the list i got was "sodetails":"[]"  . I need. like this  "sodetails":[]   without Quotes for list.

Answer (score 0):

We done it by

```
 JSONObject Full_Json = new JSONObject();
                    JSONObject params_Json = new JSONObject();
                    params_Json.put(Constant.emp_gid, Integer.parseInt(UserDetails.getUser_id()) );
                    params_Json.put(Constant.soheader_gid, 0);
                    params_Json.put(Constant.customer_gid, cust_gid);
                    params_Json.put(Constant.Action, "Insert");
                    params_Json.put(Constant.Data, new JSONObject().put(Constant.sodetails, soDetails));
                    Full_Json.put(Constant.params, params_Json);
```

soDetails is a Json array